# Does RDS DB instance endpoint changes after failover

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to know if RDS DB instance endpoint changes after failover

Answer (score 2):

No the endpoint does not change, only the DNS record is updated.

> The failover mechanism automatically changes the Domain Name System (DNS) record of the DB instance to point to the standby DB instance.

See the [RDS manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html#Concepts.MultiAZ.Failover.Java-DNS) for more info

I would highly recommend to manually test failover with your application. A failover can be simulated by rebooting an RDS instance and enabling failover.